# Can "niemand" be used alone to mean nobody as in "I am a nobody" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I have to make a design for someone and he wants me to have the word "niemand" repeated to mean "nobody" as in "I am a nobody". He doesn't speak German but needs German in the design. I just want to be sure that it actually makes sense and would be used in German or if there is another word to use to get the point across. Thank you.l

Answer (score 4):

*I am **a** nobody.* translates fine into *Ich bin **ein** Niemand.* Mind the caps on *Niemand*. If you left out the article, it had to be written without caps, because it's not a noun then – if it isn't a name, in which case it needs caps again.

<sup>from a comment</sup>